# Delete unused entries shared between multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, many-to-many

I have a `tag` table and three `tableA`,`tableB`,`tableC` tables that are taggable along with three `tableA_tag`, `tableB_tag` and `tableC_tag` tables to join them.

My application allows to remove tags from `tableA`, `tableB` or `tableC` and I want to keep only the tags currently used in one of them. 
So far, I've wrote the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER plop after DELETE
ON tableA_tag
FOR EACH row
  DELETE FROM tag
  WHERE  tag.id = old.tag_id
         AND (SELECT Sum(countTags.c) AS s
              FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS c
                      FROM   tableC_tag
                      WHERE  tag_id = old.tag_id
                      UNION
                      SELECT Count(*) AS c
                      FROM   tableB_tag
                      WHERE  tag_id = old.tag_id) countTags) = 0; 

/* Same trigger for table tableB_tag  */

/* And same again for table tableC_tag */
```

But it doesn't work because it checks if the tag is still used in `tableC_tag` or `tableB_tag` but does not check in `tableA_tag` and can so delete tags even if they are still in use. And I cannot check `tableA_tag` because it's the same table that fired the trigger.

So, how can I do ?

Comment: Why do you want to remove tags? Now they unused, but tomorrow probably they whould be used again.

Comment: You are firing trigger "after delete on tableA_tag". There is no need to check it inside the trigger. Check if tag is required before firing delete query on tableA_tag. That will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works...

```
CREATE TRIGGER plop after DELETE

ON tableA_tag

FOR EACH row

  DELETE FROM tag

  WHERE  tag.id = old.tag_id 

    and not exists(select ' ' from tableC_tag where tableC_tag.tag_id =tag.id)
    and not exists(select ' ' from tableB_tag where tableB_tag.tag_id =tag.id)   
    and not exists(select ' ' from tableA_tag where tableA_tag.tag_id =tag.id);
```

Comment: This won't because tableA_tag is still unchecked (same as what I wrote) and may still contain the tag.

Comment: Well, I don't actually understand very well why I was getting a conflict about `tableA_tag` when updating `tableA` and checking `tableA_tag` within the trigger with my trigger and not with yours, but anyway, it works :) Thank you !